# Why any permutation defines an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions, automorphism-group

My professor kept on saying that: any permutation defines an automorphism.

**My questions are:**

1-Is there a rigor proof for this fact please?

I know that a permutation of a set $M$ is a bijective function from M to itself. And I know that an automorphism is an isomorphism from M to itself and that makes every permutation an automorphism. Is this the only reason for saying that any permutation defines an automorphism.

2-And what is the normal automorphism defined by any permutation?

Comment: An automorphism of a set is just a map with an inverse; are you asking why a bijection has an inverse?

Comment: No, I am asking exactly why any permutation defines an automorphism? .... is the reason that I stated correct? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: It depends on what your definition of an automorphism is. What's your definition of an automorphism of a set? Mine is "a function with an inverse."

Comment: I stated my definition above in the question.@QiaochuYuan

Comment: You define an automorphism as an isomorphism from $M$ to itself. What is your definition of an isomorphism of sets? Mine is, again, "a function with an inverse."

Comment: Sorry I meant an automorphism is an isomorphism from a group to itself  @QiaochuYuan

Comment: What is the group? Your first sentence says "any permutation defines an automorphism" but you don't specify an automorphism of what. Later you say "a permutation of a set $M$" so I assumed you were talking about a set. Were you actually talking about a group this whole time? If so, what group, and what permutation of it?

Comment: I do not know the intension of my professor .... it is a statement he used to use and I do not know why he is saying this, this is why I am asking here.@QiaochuYuan I am trying to guess what he meant .... and I am asking here so that I can find more educated people than me to help me.

Comment: You should just ask your professor - we can't read their mind - but I think your professor just meant that a permutation is an automorphism of a *set*, which just means exactly that a permutation has an inverse.

Comment: He was speaking about that $\operatorname {Aut} (V) \cong S_{3}$ and in the proof he used the fact that any permutation defines an automorphism.

Comment: What is $V$?  Automorphism of what?  It's not true that every permutation of the elements of a group is a group automorphism, for example.

Comment: V is the klein 4 group @saulspatz

Comment: How in the world was anyone supposed to guess that from your question?  It's certainly not true that every permutation of the elements of the group is a group automorphism, since an automorphism must carry the identity to the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An automorphism of a structure $\mathfrak{A}$ - being deliberately loose about what I mean by "structure" - is a permutation of the elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ which preserves all the relevant operations and relations. For example, if $\mathfrak{A}$ is just a set with no additional structure then "automorphism of $\mathfrak{A}$" is the same as "permutation of $\mathfrak{A}$," and this is what Qiaochu's initial comments above were getting at. By contrast, an automorphism of a group is more complicated: it has to preserve the "group structure," which is to say it has to satisfy the following rules:

- $f(e)=e$,
- $f(x^{-1})=f(x)^{-1}$, and
- $f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$.

Any nontrivial group has permutations which are not automorphisms (just consider any permutation moving the identity). So taken too literally, the slogan "Any permutation defines an automorphism" is blatantly false for every interesting group.

---

However, that's not what your professor meant: there's a more nuanced interpretation which some groups (such as the Klein four group $V$) satisfy while others don't (exercise).

Specifically, some structures - and in particular, some groups - have a very nice property: that their automorphisms "are" permutations *of some other set*. This is especially interesting when that other set is a subset of the structure itself.

The Klein four group $V$ provides an example of this. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be the non-identity elements of $V$; every permutation $\pi$ of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ extends to a unique automorphism $\alpha_\pi$ of $V$, and conversely every automorphism of $V$ restricts to a permutation of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$.

**This is not in general the case!** If $G$ is an arbitrary group, there's no reason for $Aut(G)$ to be isomorphic to $S_X$ for any $X$. So we're seeing here a very special property of $V$.

And as a follow-up exercise:

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $Aut(G)=S_n$. Need there be some $\{a_1,...,a_n\}\subseteq G$ such that every permutation of $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ extends to a unique automorphism of $G$?

Comment: Can you show me the proof of that last exercise please?